# How to call a setState when click on leaflet marker react typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, react-leaflet

I have a list of equipment and I'm displaying they with `Array.map` and I have a Context API that has a state `[selectedEquipmentId, setSelectedEquipmentId]`.

I want that when I click on the `<Marker/>` call the `setSelectedEquipmentId(equipmentId)`.
It's a simple `onClick`, but the source way don't work with leaflet and I cant find the answer for this.

```
function Map() {
  const equipmentsPositions = useContext(EquipmentsPositionContext);
  const setSelectedEquipmentId = useContext(EquipmentIdContext);

  const center: LatLngExpression = [-19.151801, -46.007759];


  function getEquipmentById(equipmentId: string) {
    const filteredEquipment = equipmentsStateHistory.filter(
      (equipment) => equipment.equipmentId === equipmentId
    );

    return filteredEquipment[0];
  }

  return (
    <Box h="100vh" w="80%">
      <MapContainer
        center={center}
        zoom={10}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />

        {equipmentsPositions?.map((equipmentPosition) => {
          const equipment = getEquipmentById(equipmentPosition.equipmentId);

          return (
            <Marker
              onClick={() => {setSelectedEquipmentId(equipment.equipmentId)}}
              key={equipment.equipmentId}
              position={[
                equipmentPosition.positions[equipmentsPositions.length - 1].lat,
                equipmentPosition.positions[equipmentsPositions.length - 1].lon,
              ]}
            >
              <Popup>
                <Text as="span" color={equipment.color}>
                  {equipment.name}
                </Text>
              </Popup>
            </Marker>
          );
        })}

      </MapContainer>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

And here is the `Context` just to context haha

```
interface ISelectedEquipmentIdContext {
  selectedEquipmentId: string | ReactNode;
  setSelectedEquipmentId: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
}

export const EquipmentIdContext = createContext<ISelectedEquipmentIdContext | null>(
  null
);

export function EquipmentIdProvider({ children }: IProps) {
  const [selectedEquipmentId, setSelectedEquipmentId] = useState<string>("");

  return (
    <EquipmentIdContext.Provider value={{ selectedEquipmentId: selectedEquipmentId, setSelectedEquipmentId: setSelectedEquipmentId }}>
      {children}
    </EquipmentIdContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I've tried a lot of things, and nothing works

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt have state declaration as

> const [selectedEquipmentId, setSelectedEquipmentId] = useState("");

and interface as

> selectedEquipmentId: string | ReactNode;

because ReactNode cannot be string. So if you don't need ReactNode should remove it, if you need it for some reason need to add it to state type.

Can also do `ISelectedEquipmentIdContext['selectedEquipmentId']` but for an Id you most likely just want the string type.